# Difference between parameters.yml and config.yml in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I don't understand the difference between these two ways of setting global constants in Symfony2. Is it only about being able to set default values and types in config.yml (+configuration.php) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, nope, nope.

`parameters.yml` is for passwords and server specific parameters such as database connection information.

The main difference between `config.yml` (and all the other config files) and `parameters.yml` is that `parameters.yml` should never be checked in to your source control system.  Doing so will expose your passwords and other private information to whomever has access to your source code.

Answer (score 3):

**parameters.yml** file is the place for all constants that are environment dependent. If you use composer to deploy your app it will ask you about their values. You can also define **paramteters.yml.dist** to provide some defaults values. If you use **parameters.yml** you have all parameters needed to setup an application (for example on production server) in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way to separate some independent data in files. You can put in your config.yml all the data located in another config-files (parameters.yml, routing.yml, security.yml and so on). But it will be hard to maintain the whole project even if you are the single developer on the project.

All config data should be splitted according to their domain. Settings for email - in email-settings file, settings for integrating payment system - in payment-settings file, services - in services-config file.

If you have some personal information in the config files you can add this file to `.gitignore` and define some default values to the `your_config.yml.dist`. Then you can set up your composer to run some script to fill `your_config.yml` file like it has been made in symfony standard edition.